# Strange Facebook Access Requests

Tags: facebook, security

There are quite a few posts on her talking about Facebook's access of people's sites but nobody seems to be having the same problem as me.

Basically, I've been having problems with a site I manage, with the site going down regularly, 401 Forbidden error pages cropping up reguarly, as well as Server Configuration Error pages, although only ever sporadically. I've been trying everything to work out the issue but no luck as of yet. However, one thing that seems strange is the following messages that I'm getting in the access logs. Now, this shouldn't be a problem as Facebook often creates messages like these when it's accessing files from a server. However, there are thousands of messages like this that reference files that don't exist. Honestly, it's constantly trying to access .jpg files that don't exist and have never existed, and so I suspect this is what's causing the server to keep crashing.

Here's one of the messages:

> domain.com 173.252.88.88 - - [20/Nov/2015:13:13:46 +0000] "GET /uploads/2009/9/28/873128bf77.jpg HTTP/1.1" 403 379 "-" "facebookexternalhit/1.1 (+http://www.facebook.com/externalhit_uatext.php)"

Has anyone had anything similar to this before?

Thanks,
Russ

Comment: If these crawler requests are coming in at excessive rates, can you be sure that this is really coming from Facebook?